# Insertar etiquetas HTML de manera dinámica

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Quiero insertar filas dinámicamente y que cada vez que lo haga, el nombre de la variable aumente en `1`.

```
var textoBusqueda = $("#NUMERO_ITEM1").val();

if (textoBusqueda != "") {
    $.post("buscar.php", {valorBusqueda: textoBusqueda}, function(mensaje) {
        $("#DESCRIPCION_ITEM1").html(mensaje);
    }); 
} else { 
    $("#DESCRIPCION_ITEM1").html('Ingrese numero de item');
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

busqueda dinamica y guarda el historico aqui el codigo

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
var i = 1;
 $(document).on("click","#btn_buscar",function() {
 
  var textoBusqueda = $("#NUMERO_ITEM1").val();
   if (textoBusqueda != "") {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/" + i,
        method: "GET",
        data: { textoBusqueda: textoBusqueda }
      }).done(function(data) {
          $("#DESCRIPCION_BUSQUEDA").append(" <div id='DESCRIPCION_BUSQUEDA_" + i +"'>"+ textoBusqueda + ": " +data.title + "</div>");
          i++;
          $("#NUMERO_ITEM1").val("");
      });
     
   } else { 
      $("#DESCRIPCION_BUSQUEDA").append('Ingrese numero de item');
      };

  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="form">
<input type="text" id="NUMERO_ITEM1" name="NUMERO_ITEM1" />
<button id="btn_buscar" > Buscar</button>
<div id="DESCRIPCION_BUSQUEDA">
</div>
</div>
```

si quieres quitas el codigo ajax, lo deje como ejemplo para mostrar el resultado