# Incrementar variables dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Quiero incrementar la variable de cada uno de los campos 
(`NUMERO_ITEM1`, `DESCRIPCION_ITEM1`) dinámica mente, es decir

`DESCRIPCION_ITEM1`, `DESCRIPCION_ITEM2`... `DESCRIPCION_ITEMn`...

Por medio de la variable `$post` realizo la consulta.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#resultadoBusqueda").html('Vacio');  });

  function buscar() {

var textoBusqueda = $("#NUMERO_ITEM1").val();

if (textoBusqueda != "") {
  $.post("buscar.php", {valorBusqueda: textoBusqueda}, function(mensaje) {
      $("#DESCRIPCION_ITEM1").html(mensaje);
   }); 
} else { 
  $("#DESCRIPCION_ITEM1").html('Vacio');  };
```

Comment: que paso con esta respuesta? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/76696/insertar-etiquetas-html-de-manera-din%C3%A1mica/76711#76711

Comment: No me me funciono

Comment: y por que no insististe?, que no te funciono del ejemplo?

Comment: Disculpas, la verdad que es que soy nuevo en todo esto de la Stack y programacion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

deberas de usar una variable para hacer uso del incrementable, de la siguietne manera.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#resultadoBusqueda").html('Vacio');  });        

    function buscar() {

    var autoincremento = 0; <-- INICIAS EL AUTO INCREMENTABLE
    var textoBusqueda = $("#NUMERO_ITEM1").val();

    if (textoBusqueda != "") {

       $.ajax({
         url: "buscar.php",
         type: "POST",
         dataType: "JSON", // Tipo de archivo de respuesta en este caso sera un JSON
         data: {
           // parametro: variable // agrego las variables de consulta si son necesarias
         },
         success: function(data){

           var html = '';
           $.each(data,function(indice,fila){
              html += '<input value="' + fila['campo'] + '">';
           });

           $('#mycampo').html(html);

         }
       });

    } else { 
      $("#DESCRIPCION_ITEM"+(autoincremento++)).html('Vacio');  };
```

Comment: No me funciona Jesus :( te explico un poco mas. inserto dinamicamente las filas para el mismo FORM y la forma en la que lo tengo trabajando ahora es duplicar el codigo ya mensionado anteriormente, como tantas filas hayan (NUMERO_ITEM1, NUMERO_ITEM2... DESCRIPCION_ITEM1, DESCRIPCION_ITEM2 ...) de esa forma me funciona, pero obvio es mucho codigo y nada minimalista, al copiar el codigo y ajustarlo parece que no toma el numero del input, te agradezco tu ayuda.

Comment: osea que lo que necesitas es agregar cantidad de elementos que traigas de la consulta y mostrarla en un elemento, correcto?

Comment: tengo n filas, y en cada fila tengo NUMERO_ITEMn y DESCRIPCION_ITEMn, esos input se generar dinamicamente. y el item y la descripcion estan almacenados en una tabla, cosa que yo escribo el numero_item y automaticamente me devuelva la descripcion. despues de eso tendre que capturarlos e insertarlos en otra tabla diferente, espero me entiendas.

Comment: acabo de modificar el código, usuaria el que puse en vez del tuyo, así puedo tener mayor control de el y de la respuesta

Comment: Serias tan amable de explicarme el codigo despues de dataType, sieto molestarte pero realmente todo es es nuevo para mi.

Comment: por ejemplo, tienes 3 inputs de un formulario con los siguientes ID: id1, id2 y id3, en data pones lo siguiente -> data : { in1: id1, in2: id2, in3: id3 }. de esta manera podras enviar parametros a la url indicada

Comment: asi podras enviar los datos, ya sea el value o el atributo que desees, obviamente instanciado en una variable.

Comment: En este caso tengo una tabla, que es la fila, y se genera dinamicamente de la misma forma se generan todos los input y el ID tambien incrementa asi: $('#btAdd').click(function() { if (iCnt <= 49) {iCnt + 1; // Añadir tabla.
            $(container).append('<table id=tableid' + iCnt + '><tr><td><//todos los inputs con sus ID ' + iCnt + ' ></tr><td>);

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con el siguiente código:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#resultadoBusqueda").html('Vacio');  });

    function buscar() {

    var textoBusqueda = $("#NUMERO_ITEM1").val();

    if (textoBusqueda != "") { 

      $.post( "buscar.php", { valorBusqueda: textoBusqueda })
          .done(function( data ) {
             $("#DESCRIPCION_ITEM1").html(data);
          })
          .fail(function(data) {
            alert( "error" + data );
          });
    } else { 
          $("#DESCRIPCION_ITEM1").html('Vacio');  
    }
   }
```

Comment: Andres no comprendo que hace el código, serias tan amable de explicarme por que no veo que utilice alguna forma de incrementar las variables.

Answer (score 0):

No tuve tiempo de implementar tu caso con el ejemplo que te hice. Puedes guiarte con esto que acabo de hacer.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var object = {}; //DECLARAS UNA VARIABLE DE TIPO OBJETO, CUANDO SON LLAVES, SERAN OBJETOS
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
 var chain = "NUMERO_ITEM"+i;//A TU VARIABLE CHAIN LE PONES EL NOMBRE MAS DONDE VAYA i
  object[chain] = 'VALOR '+i;//A TU OBJETO EN SU INDICE CHAIN OSEA OBJETO_0 POR EJEMPLO LE ASIGNAS UN VALOR, EN ESTE CASO VALOR0
}
alert(object.NUMERO_ITEM0);//CAMBIA EL NUMERO, POR EJEMPLO object.NUMERO_ITEM8

</script>
```

Les dejo el Fiddle también

> https://jsfiddle.net/7feuvqLp/1/